# customer undefined trying to check if logged in

Tags: magento2, javascript, customer

I'm trying to display a registration pop-up only if a user has never seen it before and it occurred to me it would be wise to also check to make sure they were not already logged in.

But when I follow the suggestions I have seen to use Magento_Customer/js/model/customer, customer ends up being undefined so I can't check customer.isLogged();

Am I missing something?

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer",
    "mage/cookies"
], function ($, customer) {
    "use strict";
    return function myscript() {
        // it was failing setting the variable so I added this
        console.log('in myscript', customer);
        // the console shows that customer is undefined
        var isLoggedIn = customer.isLoggedIn();
        var regMsgSeen = $.mage.cookies.get('regMsgSeen');
        if(!regMsgSeen && !isLoggedIn) {
            $(document).ready(
                function () {
                    $.mage.cookies.set('regMsgSeen',1,{});
                    setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            $('div#zoo-register-form').modal('openModal');
                        }, 1000);
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons of this case:

1. `customer.isLoggedIn()` method in `Magento_Customer/js/model/customer` check if global var `window.isCustomerLoggedIn` is true. For first look this var is defined only in Checkout + Cart. So you will get undefined for the rest pages.
2. I know that Magento makes AJAX request for update sectionDate when user enter to page 1-st time, do login or clear local cache. In this response there is "customerData" object. You have to check if this request is related with `customer.isLoggedIn()` method (for first look -> no, but maybe it will be tip for you)

Comment: I think it's not loaded yet, so it probably is some kind of ajax thing. I saw one example that uses the jquery deferred, but I'm not familiar with how that process works, no less in conjunction with magento no less in conjunction with another script.